# How to disable intervals < d3.time.day for automatic ticks?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I defined my xaxis in a way that the date (day and month) is displayed with every tick.

```js
chart.xAxis
.showMaxMin(true)                                             
.tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%d.%m')(new Date(d)) });                         

var scale = d3.time.scale();                                  
chart.xScale(scale);
```

According to the d3 wiki, the scale of the x-axis is automatically adjusted depending on the range of the values (see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#ticks).

When I select a small range of days now in a large graph (for example 3 days), d3 falls back to d3.time.hour, because there is enough space to break down a day into hours and display all the resulting ticks.
Regarding to the format, this results in the fact that every day is displayed multiple times.

How can I achieve that no interval smaller than d3.time.day is considered by d3?

Comment: You can use a [custom time format](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4149176).

Comment: Can you provide a complete example please?

Comment: Those are deprecated from D3 V4 onwards. Here's [an updated example for v4](https://bl.ocks.org/wboykinm/34627426d84f3242e0e6ecb2339e9065) - credit to [this answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46045791/568458)